# How to avoid including login credentials on each php page, storing the credentials in a single page and adjusting code to match adjustments

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to do a simple image upload and store a few data, however I want to remove the section(s) of the code that have the direct database username password and host, with a simple `include("config.php")` in the heading. So what I am asking apart from the `include("config.php")` line how would I make adjustments to the code example:`$conn = $db->prepare($query);` an so on

```
<?php

include("config.php");
define('UPLOAD_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'photohandling/uploads/');
define('DISPLAY_PATH', '/photohandling/uploads/');
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 2000000);
$permitted = array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif','image/tiff');
$dames2=time();

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = 'password';
$db_name = 'test';

if (!empty($_POST)){

    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$acquirer_bin=$_POST['acquirer_bin'];
$terminal_id=$_POST['terminal_id'];
$trace_id=$_POST['trace_id'];




    // get the file extension 
    $ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
    // generate the random file name
    $randName = md5(rand() * time());

    // image name with extension
    $myfile = $acquirer_bin.$trace_id.$dames2.$randName . '.' . $ext;
    // save image path
    $path = UPLOAD_PATH . $myfile;


    if (in_array($fileType, $permitted) && $fileSize > 0 && $fileSize <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        //store image to the upload directory
        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $path);

        if (!$result) {
            echo "Error uploading image file";
            exit;
        } else {
            $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "hynes21", "test");

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s<br/>", mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            $query =
              "INSERT INTO tester(fname,lname,age, acquirer_bin, terminal_id, trace_id,photo_name, size, type, file_path) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $conn = $db->prepare($query);
            if ($conn == TRUE) {
                $conn->bind_param("ssiisisiss",$fname,$lname,$age,$acquirer_bin,$terminal_id,$trace_id, $myfile, $fileSize, $fileType, $path);
                if (!$conn->execute()) {
                    echo 'error insert';
                } else {
                    echo 'Success!<br/>';
                    echo '<img src="' . DISPLAY_PATH . $myfile . '"/>';
                }
            } else {
                die("Error preparing Statement");
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'error upload file';
    }
} else {
    echo 'error';
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't define database credentials in code. A solid why to do this is to use a configuration file. `PHP` provides a built in function called `parse_ini_file` that is perfect for retrieving data from config files (in a certain format ofc).

Here is an example of a `ini` file that can be parsed by [**parse_ini_file [docs]**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

```
[db]
host = localhost
user = root
pass = password
database = test
```

As you can see the format of the file is very similar to the `php.ini` file.

Keep this `db.ini` file in a place that is not accessible by the web server but can be read by `PHP`.

Here is a function that can utilize the data in the ini file and create a new mysqli object for you.

```
// somefile.php
function new_db() {
    $info = parse_ini_file('db.ini', true);
    return new mysqli($info['db']['host'], 
                      $info['db']['user'],
                      $info['db']['pass'], 
                      $info['db']['database']);
}
```

To use your `new_db` function.

```
require_once 'somefile.php';
$db = new_db();
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the values defined in config.php. If so, this is all you need to do:

config.php

```
define(DB_HOST, 'localhost');
define(DB_USER, 'root');
define(DB_PASS, 'hynes21');
define(DB_NAME, 'test');
```

php file from where config.php is included

Option 1:

```
$db_host = DB_HOST;
$db_user = DB_USER;
$db_pass = DB_PASS;
$db_name = DB_NAME;

$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

Option 2:

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

And yeah, a heap of ppl will tell you to use PDO instead of mysqli. Indeed you should, but that's doesn't give you an answer to your question :)

Comment: What happens when `config.php` is included twice?

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but you could also do this instead of using include:

require_once('config.php');

Comment: 1. your example is not valid PHP. 2. if you `include 'config.php'` twice and you have unguarded `define` statements you get a `PHP Notice`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say in your config.php file you have this:

```
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPass = 'hynes21';
$dbName = 'test';
```

Then in your code above you would replace this line:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "hynes21", "test");
```

with this:

```
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
```

and the rest of your code should just work, thanks to variable scoping.

You could also put the db connection in the config.php file as well, which would allow you to destroy the stored connection info variables so they wouldn't be hanging around anywhere for accidental output:

```
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPass = 'hynes21';
$dbName = 'test';
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
unset($dbHost);
unset($dbUser);
unset($dbPass);
unset($dbName);
```

This would mean every page load would have the overhead of calling mysqli(), even if that page didn't use the database. But if you have a data driven site then virtually every page will want to call mysqli() anyway so that's not such a big deal.

Later on you may want to look in to using a database wrapper so you don't have to store your DB connection in a locally scoped variable, but this approach will work just fine for simple applications.

Comment: Creating globally accessible objects as a side effect of including a file is just bad practice.

Comment: I agree with you, but the OP didn't ask about best practices.